# self-join on xml slow

Tags: xml, t-sql

I have a table with some fields extracted and some xml

Each product has a masterid, so all colours or sizes of the same product have the same masterid. I want to enter any of the variants and get all variants.

I find the masterID by this:

```
xml.value('(/product/attribute-list/attribute[@name="variation_master_product_id"]/value[@default="1"])[1]','char(11)') master
```

The table is (partly) like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[products_xml](
    [varenr] [varchar](14) NOT NULL,
    [ean] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [title] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [xml] [xml] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_xml] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [varenr] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

`
I'm doing a CTE for self-join to find all products which have the same master_ID

```
;with p as (SELECT [varenr]
,xml.value('(/product/attribute-list/attribute[@name="variation_master_product_id"]/value[@default="1"])[1]','char(11)') master
      ,[ean]
      ,[title]
      ,[xml]
  FROM [products_xml]
  ) select * from p p1 inner join p p2 
on p1.master=p2.master 
and p2.varenr like '277028%'
```

The query works as expected, but it is painfully slow, takes 10 seconds to run on approximate 8000 records.

I have added the primary XML index and the 3 secondary XML-indexes, according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/xml-indexes-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017 but I don't know how to use them in this context.

```
`
```

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve], at least provide a sample of your XML. As a quick shot, you might try to add a *persisted computed column* to your table and place an index on it.

Comment: Use a temporary table instead of the CTE. Alternatively, use a HASH JOIN hint.